# I need to simplify my query in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to pull some rows from a SQL Server database using some EMP email as the filter and I need to arrange the result to fill the column space of the requirement file in Excel.

```
SELECT
    [FullName], [EmpleMail], [Manager]
FROM
    Table1
WHERE  
    [EmpleMail] IN ('email1', 'email2', '...emailN')
ORDER BY 
    CASE EmpleMail
        WHEN 'email1' THEN 1
        WHEN 'email2' THEN 2
        WHEN '...emailN' THEN N
```

The emails are in thousands.

I was expecting my records to maintain their positions so I can copy them in correct order and paste in the excel column space.

But I'm getting this error:

> Msg 8621, Level 17, State 1
> The query processor ran out of stack space during query optimization. Please simplify the query.

Comment: What is the logic behind the ordering of emails?

Answer (score 3):

If you know the list of e-mails and their desired order, stuff them in a table. Preferably, a *permanent* table, if you are doing this often, but a #temp table will do:

```
CREATE TABLE #e
(
  email nvarchar(320) not null primary key,   
  ordering int
);

INSERT #e(email, ordering) VALUES
  ('email1',1),
  ('email2',2),
  ...
  ('email1000',1000);

INSERT #e(email, ordering) VALUES
  ('email1001',1001),
  ('email1002',1002),
  ...
  ('email2000',2000);

...
```

Then you can avoid hard-coding any of that mess (twice) in the final query:

```
Select t.[FullName], t.[EmpleMail], t.[Manager] 
  From dbo.Table1 AS t 
  INNER JOIN #e AS e 
  ON t.[EmpleMail] = e.email 
  ORDER BY e.ordering;
```

Comment: You do not need a table, you can use the data in a virtual table in the sql - but then you have to rewrite the sql on any data change.

Comment: @TomTom A virtual table where you hard-code thousands of constants might suffer the same fate as the OP's current query. The goal (at least IMHO) is to simplify the query, not alter the complexity only slightly.

Comment: I am not sure I would call it a simplification - especailly as the virtual table can be autoconstructed - the OP gives no context at all. Also not about how many rows he has....

Comment: @TomTom it is a vast simplification of _the final query_, which is the one that they currently have issues with (`The query processor ran out of stack space during query optimization. Please simplify the query.`). Also they said, `The emails are in thousands.` And I have no idea how a virtual table could be auto-constructed because the OP doesn't tell us where this list of thousands of e-mail addresses comes from. Maybe you should post an answer instead of telling me I don't need a table in mine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a temporary table to store the searched emails. For example:

```
create table #tmp_emails (email varchar(50), seq int);

insert into #tmp_emails (email, seq) values ('email1', 1);
insert into #tmp_emails (email, seq) values ('email2', 2);
insert into #tmp_emails (email, seq) values ('email5000', 5000);

select t.*
from table1 t
join #tmp_emails e on e.email = t.emplemail
order by e.seq
```

It's possible to compress all inserts into a single one, but if you have too many of them you could reach some SQL statement limits doing so.